subtotal calculations not working correctly
I am trying to get this calculation to work correctly but it seems that I am unable to get it working....
What it should do is add the following (flower + colour = amount) x size = total amount for example when (rose 1.2 + white 1.3) is selected it should x by size lets say medium 7.5 selected and give a total which is 10.00 it should be 18.75 which is incorrect at the moment  when I try It the calculations are incorrect it coming back with a incorrect value .. I've looked at the code again and can't see where i'm going wrong here's the code for the calculations...
subtotal = flowerChoice == 1 ? rosePrice :  // Use ternary operator for flower price
                             flowerChoice == 2 ? lilyPrice :
                             flowerChoice == 3 ? carnationsPrice :
                             flowerChoice == 4 ? daffodilPrice :
                             flowerChoice == 5 ? gerberaPrice :
                             flowerChoice == 6 ? chrysanthemumPrice :
                             assortedPrice;

subtotal += colourChoice == 1 ? whitePrice :  // Use ternary operator for color price
                        colourChoice == 2 ? redPrice :
                        colourChoice == 3 ? pinkPrice :
                        colourChoice == 4 ? yellowPrice :
                        colourChoice == 5 ? bluePrice :
                        mixedPrice;

subtotal += sizeChoice == 1 ? smallPrice :  // Use ternary operator for size price
                         sizeChoice == 2 ? mediumPrice : largePrice;

            System.out.printf("Subtotal: £%.2f\n", subtotal);

also what I would like it to do is this print out the chosen flower +  chosen colour +              chosen size = to total amount:
any help is really appreciated
;-)
tim
what it should do is add the following (flower + colour = amount) x size = total amount for example when (rose 1.2 + white 1.3) is selected it should x by size lets say medium 7.5 selected and give a total which is 10.00 it should be 18.75

This is ternary hell, why don't you use the switch case statement or if else statements?

code is adding in subtotal += sizeChoice == ... -- it probably should multiply by size price: subtotal *= ... -- and instead of repeating yourself, it would be nicer to add better explanation

"is selected it should x by size"   I agree with the comment from @user85421. This bug is the result of a typo.

Off-topic: I agree that nested ternary operator is a poor choice. I would suggest creating class Flower, class Colour, and using arrays. If Colour[] is an attribute of Flower, this would allow the "red" price for roses to be different than "red" price for carnations. Also, this would allow flower / color combinations to be more realistic. As it is now, the user could order blue daffodils or red daffodils. (On the other hand, florists are able to offer flowers with unnatural colors by putting food coloring into the plants' water.)


what it should do is add the following (flower + colour = amount) x size = total amount for example when (rose 1.2 + white 1.3) is selected it should x by size lets say medium 7.5 selected and give a total which is 10.00 it should be 18.75

As commented, your code is "ternary hell". Use a ternary operator only where it makes your code easier to read and comprehend, not worse.
Switch expression

any help is really appreciated

Instead, use a switch expression.
int flowerChoice = 3;  // User input.
double flowerPrice =
        switch ( flowerChoice )
        {
            case 1 -> 1.1; // Lily
            case 2 -> 1.2; // Carnation
            case 3 -> 1.3; // …
            case 4 -> 1.4;
            case 5 -> 1.5;
            case 6 -> 1.6;
            default -> -666;
        };

The flow-of-control runs through each of the case statements until a match is found. The expression then returns the value for that particular case. We use default to handle any unexpected value for flowerChoice.
Do the same for color price.
int colorChoice = 2;  // User input.
double colorPrice =
        switch ( flowerChoice )
        {
            case 1 -> 0.1; // Red
            case 2 -> 0.2; // Pink
            case 3 -> 0.3; // …
            case 4 -> 0.4;
            case 5 -> 0.5;
            default -> -666;
        };

Now we have what we need to perform the calculation.
double price = flowerPrice + colorChoice;

int quantity = 3;  // User input.
double extendedCost = price * quantity;

Dump to console.
System.out.println( "extendedCost = " + extendedCost );

When run:
extendedCost = 9.899999999999999


There are much better ways to approach your overall programming for this business problem, such as using records, enums, or Map. But I limited this Answer to focusing on the more immediate issue of selecting one of several numbers and performing a calculation.

By the way, in real work, never use floating-point types where accuracy matters such as for money. Instead move the decimal point over to use whole integers such as pence, or use BigDecimal.

maybe throwing an IllegalArgumentException would be better than returning -666

@user85421 Sure. I was trying to keep it simple.

thanks guys I didn't see that, I changed the subtotal size to * and it worked perfectly. you guys are amazing! as you can see I'm just starting out in java this is my first project. I'm already using a switch method for the menu but I was wondering rather than using break; is there a way to go back to the main menu each time and repeat the menu process by using maybe a if / else statement?

the O/P could use the variable names from the question instead of numeric literals in the answer:  ... case 6 -> chrysanthemumPrice; default -> assortedPrice; ...
